# Unable to find Spring bean in Fuse Project

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm setting the body of a Camel route using a Bean. That works on a Camel standalone project. When deployed on JBoss Fuse the Spring bean is not found. Here is a snippet of the blueprint:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">


    <bean id="personFactory" class="sample.PersonFactory" />
    <bean id="myBean" class="sample.Person" />

    <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" xmlns:order="http://fusesource.com/examples/order/v7">

  <route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1"/>
    <setProperty propertyName="name">
      <constant>John</constant>
    </setProperty>
    <setProperty propertyName="surname">
      <constant>Doe</constant>
    </setProperty>

     <setBody>
      <spel>#{@personFactory.createPerson(properties['name'],properties['surname'])}
      </spel>
    </setBody>

 . . . .
  </route>
</camelContext>


</blueprint>
```

When deployed on Fuse, the following exception is raised:

```
org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'personFactory'
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem recently. Unfortunately, did not managed to resolve this using spel and have switched to simple. This should help in your case:

```js
<simple>${bean:personFactory?method=createPerson(property.name, property.surname)}</simple>
```